# Filling a List<List<String>> with values

Tags: java, arraylist, instantiation

So I've been running into a few errors. When I try to add an event to a date in a month, I try to add an event into the date `ArrayList` but the list doesn't have that number available. So I want to know how to instantiate a list that will have the amount of days in it.

I know you can instantiate how many months there are by using

```
public static List<List<String>> events = new ArrayList<List<String>>(12);
```

which 12 being the number of months, but is there a way to make all 12 of the arrays have 31 slots open for days?

Comment: That would work similar to arrays: new lists must be created explicitly in each of the 12 slots of the `events` list.

Comment: So I should use a for loop and then manually add the 31 slots?

Comment: In the case of lists, passing `12` in the constructor will only give it a capacity of 12, the list will remain empty. Just add 12 new lists to your list.

Comment: How does this work for different years?

Comment: It's not required to say in advance how many things you want to add to a List. You can perfectly add 31 (or 100 or 1000 ...) items to each of the 12 lists.  ArrayList collections start with an initial capacity, and if that turns out not to be enough it just creates more capacity as necessary. If you know in advance how many items you want to add, it helps the List be a bit more efficient, but it's quite often nothing to worry about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend completely changing your design.

- Use a map of date against event list - to deal with multiple events on same date
- Lazy initialize map. Create a method that returns list for given day/month, if it isn't there, add it.

Code

```
private class Events {
    Map<Date, List<String>> events = new HashMap<Date, List<String>>();
    public List<String> getEvents(int month, int day) {
        Calendar calendar = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(0, month, date, 0, 0, 0);
        Date date = calendar.getTime();
        List<String> list = events.get(date);
        if (list == null) {
            list = new ArrayList<String>();
            events.put(date, list);
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```

Usage

```
Events events = new Events();
events.getEvents(11, 25).add("Christmas");
events.getEvents(0, 1).add("New years day");
```

Comment: Not a bad design indeed. :0

Comment: Does the design basically behave like an Arraylist?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should change your design plan. Make a class Month with an `ArrayLisy<String>(31)` which you create 12 times in another class called year or something. For myself I would do this and it makes your code more readable!

Also, when it is a fixed number of slots (and you don't want it to go over that limit), use basic arrays

Answer (score 0):

Why not use

```
List<Map<String, Integer>> = new List<HashMap<String, Integer>>();
```

Answer (score 0):

While @Adam's answer is probably the best way to handle this particular problem, the general question of how to initialize a multidimensional list structure should also be addressed.

The standard idiom for constructing and initializing a multi-dimensional data structure like the one you describe is to use a set of `for` loops, like this:

```
int[][] myArray = new int[][myFirstDimension];
for(int i=0; i<a.length; i++){
    int [] a = new int[mySecondDimension];
    for(int j=0; j<b.length; j++){
        a[j] = myInitialValue;
    }
    myArray[i] = a;
}
```

Nested `ArrayList`s are constructed in a similar way to arrays, but with one important difference: The parameter passed to the `ArrayList` is only an initial capacity, not the initial size. In fact, `ArrayList` actually makes **no guarantees** about how much space it allocates, although in practice, IIRC, it typically allocates the next power of two. Attempting to index into the `ArrayList` before you have initialized its contents will throw an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Thus, when initializing nested `ArrayList`s, we typically do it like this:

```
List<List<String>> myList = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i=0; i<myFirstDimension; i++){
    List<String> a = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i=0; i<mySecondDimension; i++){
        a.add(""); // or `null`, if that is needed
    }
   myList.add(a);
}
```